# Redirecting to a page after post from within ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect to the action Index, controller Admin after the post from ajax.

```
$.post("/Admin/Create", { inputs: inputs, columnsCount: columnsCount, });
```

How can I change this code to redirect it to the index page after success?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use the 3rd parameter of [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post(
    "/Admin/Create", 
    { inputs: inputs, columnsCount: columnsCount, },
    function() {
        window.location.replace("/Admin/index");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

While window.location.replace or `window.location.href` definitely work, I encourage you to take a step back and think whether an Ajax call was required at all!

Ajax is used to refresh a portion of the page and when you refresh a page partially, you would not be redirecting the user to a different page.

So if you think carefully, you may be able to replace your ajax post with a regular post and redirect the user to a different action from the controller itself. This way, you will also be following the much cleaner Post-Redirect-Get pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("/Admin/Create", {
    inputs: inputs,
    columnsCount: columnsCout
}, function(){
    window.location.href = "http://..../Admin/Index";
});
```